# Single collection of reserved keywords from many programming languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax-highlighting, keyword

I am looking for a collection of lists of keywords per programming language, preferably for a large set of popular languages, preferably in a machine-readable format. I failed to find such resource just from Googling. Is anyone familiar with such a list?

Hint - Many editors have such a list as a part of their syntax highlighting configuration. I looked at the Notepad++ config file, but unfortunately it completely mixes between reserved keywords and commonly-used functions. For example, mysql functions are listed as PHP keywords.  Emacs, unfortunately, uses per-mode Lisp scripts. If you're using an editor with a textual syntax highlighting config file that clearly specifies the language-reserved keywords for a large selection of languages, please let me know.

I am **not** looking to build a language classifier or to automatically deduce the keywords from samples. These are separate tasks that were already discussed here at Stackoverflow. I am just looking for a large collection of language keywords.

Comment: Not clear whether this will meet your requirements - Textpad (http://www.textpad.com/) has configurations for multiple languages, which are separate config files. They do have a very substantial number of language syntax highlighting files.

Comment: @ChrisWalton Simple requirement: The config files should include a list of keywords per language, clearly separated from lists of built-in functions, types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) has a [large collection of Syntax files](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/extras.html) and they seem to distinguish actual reserved words from functions. Have a look and see if it fits the bill.

Comment: Almost... Not all syntax files follow the same standard. Some clearly distinguish between reserved words and auxiliaries. Other make an unnecessary distinction between control-flow keywords and structure-related keywords, such as `class` and `new`. Other files do not specify which word list is for keywords, if any.

Comment: Usually *keywords* are in the block marked /C1"Keywords" - for example for Java we have:
abstract assertbreak byte boolean
catch case class char const continue
default double do else extends
false final float for finally goto
if import implements int interface instanceof
long length native new null
package private protected public
return switch strictfp synchronized short static super
try true this throw throws threadsafe transient
void volatile while widefp -- which are all restricted keywords. I doubt you can get better than this, especially in just one place for tens of languages